# como puedo almacenar datos de un json con varios objetos en c# core.net 2.1 endpoint

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnetcore

Hola yo estoy recibiendo un datos en un json:

```
[
{
  "name": "string",
  "rol": "string",
  "idList": "0",
  "route": "string",
  "nameFile": "string"
},
{
  "name": "tomas",
  "rol": "conductor",
  "idList": "1",
  "route": "hjasgda/kasdhka/",
  "nameFile": "821391ndas.png"
},
{
  "name": "tomas",
  "rol": "conductor",
  "idList": "1",
  "route": "hjasgda/kasdhka/",
  "nameFile": "821391ndas.png"
},
{
  "name": "tomas",
  "rol": "conductor",
  "idList": "1",
  "route": "hjasgda/kasdhka/",
  "nameFile": "821391ndas.png"
}
]
```

pero este JSON cuando llega al enpoint solo puede almacenar el primer paquete de datos el resto los bota este sería mi endpoint:

```
[HttpPost("SignatureChecklist")]
        public async Task PostSignature([FromBody] ChecklistSignature filter)
        {
            await _processorSignatureCheckList.CheckListSignatureProcessor(filter);
        }
```

*¿como puedo modificar mi código para que en la variable filter se almacenen todos mis datos y nos solo uno?* **(cabe recalcar que estoy en una versión antigua de core.net 2.1 por lo cual agradeceria su ayuda)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías modificar el endpoint para que acepte una lista/array de objetos de 'ChecklistSignature'.

```
[HttpPost("SignatureChecklist")]
public async Task PostSignature([FromBody] List<ChecklistSignature> filter)
{
    await _processorSignatureCheckList.CheckListSignatureProcessor(filter);
}
```

o podes usar un array también:

```
[HttpPost("SignatureChecklist")]
public async Task PostSignature([FromBody] ChecklistSignature[] filter)
{
    await _processorSignatureCheckList.CheckListSignatureProcessor(filter);
}
```